# Why does find method return empty array in typeorm

Tags: javascript

```
  async create(
gPriceChangeDto: GPriceChangeDto,
gainerEntity: GainerEntity,
): Promise<GPriceChangeEntity> {
const findGPriceChange = await this.gPriceChangeRepository.find();
const priceChange = await this.gPriceChangeRepository.create(
  gPriceChangeDto,
);
console.log(findGPriceChange); // []
priceChange.gainer = gainerEntity;
await this.gPriceChangeRepository.save(priceChange);
await this.gPriceChangeRepository.delete(
  findGPriceChange?.map((item) => {
    return item.id;
  }),
);
return priceChange;
}
```

I have a problem that when I call the find method, it returns an empty array to me. I have a "OneToOne" relation in a file. And in the console I get this error.

```
[Nest] 8687  - 03/11/2022, 9:47:30 PM   ERROR [Scheduler] TypeORMError: Empty 
criteria(s) are not allowed for the delete method.
[Nest] 8687  - 03/11/2022, 9:47:30 PM   ERROR [Scheduler] TypeORMError: Empty 
criteria(s) are not allowed for the delete method. I am using nestjs.
```